# Maximum and minimum amont of swaps for Quicksort Algoritm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, quicksort, analysis

I have the following as a part of my assignment:

> Consider the QuickSort algorithm.
>
> i.  Give an example of an 8-element array that requires the maximum number of swap operations
> (Assume the pivot is the first element), and explain your answer.
>
> ii.  Give an example of an 8-element array that requires the minimum number of swap operations (Assume the pivot is the last element), and explain your answer.

I think the array which requires the minimum number of swap operations is the already sorted array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} since there won't be any swaps. But for the first part, I have no idea about how to approach it other than writing a code and brute-forcing it. What would be the proper approach for solving this problem?

Comment: What do you think would be the layout of values that is "hardest" for quicksort to deal with? Think of a simpler case, an array just with 3 values, for instance (it's small enough that you can quickly draw all possible cases in a paper).

Comment: @devouredelysium: IMO, the case of 3 elements is way too small to see a pattern.

Comment: What is wrong with brute forcing it, and provide your program as explanation?

Comment: @trincot I don't have a program I have to solve this on paper and provide an explanation about how I did it.

Comment: @devouredelysium I have done exactly what you said for some other algorithms such as merge sort. Since the array size is exactly half, it was much easier but in the quick-sort case I wasn't able to see a pattern.

Comment: It's going to depend on the partitioning algorithm.

Comment: Finding the maximum seems particularly difficult. It is immediate that the maximum number of swaps of a partition is the half of the subarray size. But always assuming this maximum number minimizes the total number of partitions. On the opposite, maximizing the number of partitions makes them swap-free...

Comment: Just make the program, and then write the result on paper. If it is not allowed to involved programming, then why ask it here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @trincot: this is indeed quite doable. 40230 cases to try.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: mh, the partitioning process in Quicksort is pretty standard, isn't it ? (Unless the pivot selection strategy induces constraints on the sizes of the subarrays.)

Comment: Using are ready-made QuickSort implementation (https://stackabuse.com/quicksort-in-python/), I measured minimum 0 swaps for (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), and maximum 9 for (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 0). (Counting only the swaps of distinct elements.)

Comment: *"the partitioning process in Quicksort is pretty standard, isn't it"*: no. There are many variants, and they yield different results in terms of number of swaps.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with programming:

- Produce all possible permutations of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
- Count how many swaps are needed to sort them
- Retain one that maximises that count

Additionally you can then perform the sort again on that result, and output all the swaps that are made.

The results will depend on the partitioning algorithm. Below is an implementation in JavaScript that performs the above algorithm for the Lomuto partitioning scheme and the Hoare partitioning scheme (both altered to take the left value as pivot).

You can run it here:

### Hoare

```js
function quickSortHoare(arr, start=0, end=arr.length, verbose=false) {
    if (verbose) console.log("quickSortHoare(" + arr.map((val, i) => i >= start && i < end ? val : "-").join(" ") + ")");
    let count = 0;
    if (end - start < 2) return 0;
    let pivot = arr[start];
    let i = start - 1, j = end;
    while (true) {
        do { i++ } while (arr[i] < pivot);
        do { j-- } while (arr[j] > pivot);
        if (i >= j) break;
        if (verbose) console.log("  swap values " + arr[i] + " and " + arr[j]);
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
        count++;
    }
    if (verbose) console.log("  after partitioning: " + arr.map((val, i) => i >= start && i < end ? val : "-").join(" "));
    if (i == start) i++;
    return count + quickSortHoare(arr, start, i, verbose) + quickSortHoare(arr, i, end, verbose);
}

function* permutations(arr) {
    if (arr.length <= 1) yield arr;
    else {
        let value = arr[0];
        for (let perm of permutations(arr.slice(1))) {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                yield perm.slice(0, i).concat(value, perm.slice(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

function findWorstCase(sorter) {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let worstCase;
    let maxCount = -1;
    for (let perm of permutations(arr)) {
        let count = sorter([...perm]);
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            worstCase = perm;
        }
    }
    console.log(...worstCase);
    sorter(worstCase, 0, worstCase.length, true);
    console.log(maxCount + " swaps");
}

console.log("Hoare partitioning:");
findWorstCase(quickSortHoare);
```

The result found is that 11 swaps are needed for sorting [5, 6, 8, 7, 2, 1, 4, 3] with the [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) and left most value as pivot:

```
Hoare partitioning:
5 6 8 7 2 1 4 3
quickSortHoare(5 6 8 7 2 1 4 3)
  swap values 5 and 3
  swap values 6 and 4
  swap values 8 and 1
  swap values 7 and 2
  after partitioning: 3 4 1 2 7 8 6 5
quickSortHoare(3 4 1 2 - - - -)
  swap values 3 and 2
  swap values 4 and 1
  after partitioning: 2 1 4 3 - - - -
quickSortHoare(2 1 - - - - - -)
  swap values 2 and 1
  after partitioning: 1 2 - - - - - -
quickSortHoare(1 - - - - - - -)
quickSortHoare(- 2 - - - - - -)
quickSortHoare(- - 4 3 - - - -)
  swap values 4 and 3
  after partitioning: - - 3 4 - - - -
quickSortHoare(- - 3 - - - - -)
quickSortHoare(- - - 4 - - - -)
quickSortHoare(- - - - 7 8 6 5)
  swap values 7 and 5
  swap values 8 and 6
  after partitioning: - - - - 5 6 8 7
quickSortHoare(- - - - 5 6 - -)
  after partitioning: - - - - 5 6 - -
quickSortHoare(- - - - 5 - - -)
quickSortHoare(- - - - - 6 - -)
quickSortHoare(- - - - - - 8 7)
  swap values 8 and 7
  after partitioning: - - - - - - 7 8
quickSortHoare(- - - - - - 7 -)
quickSortHoare(- - - - - - - 8)
11 swaps
```

### Lomuto

Here the same thing, but with the Lomuto based partitioning:

```js
function quickSortLomuto(arr, start=0, end=arr.length, verbose=false) {
    if (verbose) console.log("quickSortLomuto(" + arr.map((val, i) => i >= start && i < end ? val : "-").join(" ") + ")");
    let count = 0;
    if (end - start < 2) return 0;
    let pivot = arr[start];
    let i = end;
    for (let j = end - 1; j >= start; j--) {
        if (arr[j] >= pivot) {
            i--;
            if (i != j) {
                if (verbose) console.log("  swap values " + arr[i] + " and " + arr[j]);
                [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (verbose) console.log("  after partitioning: " + arr.map((val, i) => i >= start && i < end ? val : "-").join(" "));
    return count + quickSortLomuto(arr, start, i, verbose) + quickSortLomuto(arr, i + 1, end, verbose);
}

function* permutations(arr) {
    if (arr.length <= 1) yield arr;
    else {
        let value = arr[0];
        for (let perm of permutations(arr.slice(1))) {
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                yield perm.slice(0, i).concat(value, perm.slice(i));
            }
        }
    }
}

function findWorstCase(sorter) {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let worstCase;
    let maxCount = -1;
    for (let perm of permutations(arr)) {
        let count = sorter([...perm]);
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            worstCase = perm;
        }
    }
    console.log(...worstCase);
    sorter(worstCase, 0, worstCase.length, true);
    console.log(maxCount + " swaps");
}

console.log("Lomuto partitioning:");
findWorstCase(quickSortLomuto);
```

The result is that the worst case [2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3, 1] will need 16 swaps:

```
Lomuto partitioning:
2 4 6 8 7 5 3 1
quickSortLomuto(2 4 6 8 7 5 3 1)
  swap values 1 and 3
  swap values 1 and 5
  swap values 1 and 7
  swap values 1 and 8
  swap values 1 and 6
  swap values 1 and 4
  swap values 1 and 2
  after partitioning: 1 2 4 6 8 7 5 3
quickSortLomuto(1 - - - - - - -)
quickSortLomuto(- - 4 6 8 7 5 3)
  swap values 3 and 5
  swap values 3 and 7
  swap values 3 and 8
  swap values 3 and 6
  swap values 3 and 4
  after partitioning: - - 3 4 6 8 7 5
quickSortLomuto(- - 3 - - - - -)
quickSortLomuto(- - - - 6 8 7 5)
  swap values 5 and 7
  swap values 5 and 8
  swap values 5 and 6
  after partitioning: - - - - 5 6 8 7
quickSortLomuto(- - - - 5 - - -)
quickSortLomuto(- - - - - - 8 7)
  swap values 7 and 8
  after partitioning: - - - - - - 7 8
quickSortLomuto(- - - - - - 7 -)
quickSortLomuto(- - - - - - - -)
16 swaps
```

There are many variants for the partitioning scheme, and they will influence what is the worst case.